# How to avoid mutations while pushing an array inside an object

Tags: redux, react-redux, immutability

I have an object that holds a company and inside a company, there is an array of teams.

```
  company: {
    teams: [
      {
        name: 'test team',
        description: 'dddd',
        team_manager: null,
        company: '592577d5b591966c8e535865',
        permalink: 'test-team',
        createdAt: '2017-05-30T07:38:58.983Z',
        updatedAt: '2017-05-30T07:38:58.983Z',
        id: '592d219277923054118e7299'
      }
    ],
    name: 'test company2',
    createdAt: '2017-05-24T12:08:53.418Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-05-24T12:08:53.419Z',
    id: '592577d5b591966c8e535865'
  }
}
```

When a team is added, I am using this reducer to push the team to the array.

```
case types.ADD_TEAM_SUCCESS :
  return Object.assign({}, state, state.teams.push(action.newTeam));
```

This works fine, however, in the console I am getting a warning that says:

'Error: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: `company.teams.0`'

What is the correct way to close the object and push the new team to the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As describe before Object.assign() does not do a deep clone of your object.

My suggestion is normalize your store and split into two stores Company and Teams.

Than use combineReducers and connect this into one store you will simplify reducers and will make code more readable. Also you can than play with performance.

I mean ... if you will have component just working with company and you will have change in teams you will avoid easily re-render.

Check Dan Abramov grate video tutorial 
[Redux: Normalizing the State Shape](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-normalizing-the-state-shape)

I will do that somehow (sorry for code in typescript)

```
export interface ICompanyItem {    
    name: string;    
    id: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;    
}

export interface ITeamItem {
    id: string;
    companyId: string
    name: string;
    description: string;
    team_manager: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
}

export interface ICompaniesState {
    items: { [id: string]: ICompanyItem };
}

export interface ITeamsState {
    items: { [id: string]: ITeamItem };
}


export const teamsReducer: Reducer<ITeamsState> = (state: ITeamsState, action: Action) => {

    if (isActionType(action, AddNewTeamItem)) {
        let itemsClone: { [id: string]: ITeamItem } = { ...state.items, [action.id]: action.team };

        return {
            ...state,
            items: itemsClone
        };
    }

    return state || unloadedState;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I evened up splitting teams out of the company. This will make it easier to modify a team as well.

Answer (score 3):

[See this link](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html)

If you are using es2015, I you can do something like:

`return Object.assign({}, state, { teams: [...state.teams, action.newTeam] });`

You are pushing an object directly to `state.teams`. You should make a copy first and use that instead. If you can't use the spread operator, you can slice state.teams into a new variable and push to that instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Object.assign()` does not do a deep clone of your object [[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (see "Warning for Deep Clone").

If you don't have any utility libraries in your stack (like lodash) you can use JSON encoding and decoding to get the job done:

```
case types.ADD_TEAM_SUCCESS:
    let stateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
    state.teams.push(action.newTeam);
    return state;
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: That's right, but as a better practice consider using [combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) to make only one reducer responsible for managing that branch `teams` of the state

Comment: That's great advice.

Comment: Stringifying is not a good practice.  You don't want to actually "deep clone" - you wanted to do nested _shallow clones_.  See the Redux docs section on [Structuring Reducers - Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) and the [Redux FAQ on deep cloning](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-clone-state)